# MSSQL Page Split Spike on AlwaysOn Readable Secondary

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, page-splits

Recently I caught a massive page-split spike on an AlwaysOn Secondary instance that was not mimicked in any way by the active primary. I'm interested in what might cause this on a readable secondary since everything is "read-only".
[image]

Comment: Did you enabled your secondary replica for read-only workload? Why am I asking? See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2011/12/22/alwayson-impact-of-mapping-reporting-workload-on-readable-secondary-to-snapshot-isolation/).

Comment: I did, but I would expect the extra row version space to impact the primary and secondary equally .

Comment: I agree with what you said. Few things to consider in perfmon you do not know what database the splits r happening or kind of split? If you do not have XE setup(more targeted) or read the logs you will get to the bottom of this. 2 resources to consider. [First one](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/how-to-identify-the-source-of-page-splits-in-a-database/) and [2nd one](http://www.sqlserver.org.au/blogs/users/greg_linwood/permalink.aspx?id=16). There was a blog  by Greg LInwood but I cant find it. [This](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/michael_zilberstein/archive/2009/02/05/11734.aspx_ is also useful.